# React-native define component height with flexbox

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to define a list of elements with the same height, but the result is that the component takes all the available space.

This is the code:

```
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: "center"}} key={location.id}>
        <Text style={{width: "80%", height: 20}}>{location.name}</Text>
        <Button
          style={{width: "20%", height: 20}}
          title="x"
          onPress={() => this.removeLocationFromDevice(location)}
        />
      </View>
    )
```

This is the result:

[image: This is the result]

How can I make sure that the button and the text elements have just enough height to display the element and nothing more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the initial View to flex 1 and wrap the button + text in an other view

```
return (
  <View style={{flex: 1}} key='key'>
  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: "center"}}>
  <Text style={{width: "80%", height: 20}}>text</Text>
  <Button
    style={{width: "20%", height: 20}}
    title="x"
  />
  </View>
</View>
);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help: it works! Can you explain why?

Comment: I dont realy know,but i think that the button component take the same height thant the parents elements (in your case flex: 1). 
I realy don't know why. 
ps: if you use the react-native button component it may be better to use : TouchableOpacity  component.